# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|^{1/n} = L < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|^{1/n} = L < 1$. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0$.

Remark: Not use that exist $0<r<1$ number so that $0<|x_n|<r^n$

Comment: What is the point of the remark?

Comment: Do you know the root test for series?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\alpha>0$ then isn't it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|x_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use that (note though, it only holds for $n$ sufficiently large)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n|^{1/n} = L < 1.$$

Then by the root test for infinite series the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty x_n$$

converges absolutely. It is a necessary condition that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ for a series $\sum_n x_n$ to converge. (By the Cauchy criterion for series.) Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = 0.$$